# AngularJS What is the order of firing directives

Tags: angularjs

I just tried to make something with two directives but I do not understand why my `welcome` directive is firing first.

It doesn't seem to matter if I have my element defined like this `<div  goodbye welcome></div>` or this `<div welcome goodbye></div>`. Either way the `welcome` directive is always firing first.

```
<body ng-app="greetings">
    <div  goodbye welcome></div>
</body>

angular.module('greetings', [])
.directive("goodbye", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(){
      alert("See ya later!");
    }
  }
})
.directive("welcome", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(){
      alert("Howdy!");
    }
  }
});
```

**What do I need to change in code above to have it such that the `goodbye` directive fires first?**

Comment: _"but always welcome directive is firing first"_ No, it doesn't. It depends on the browser.

Comment: what do u mean by browser. r u trying to say output will be different based on browser FF, chrome, IE etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a **priority** on your directives:

```
<body ng-app="greetings">
    <div  goodbye welcome></div>
</body>

angular.module('greetings', [])
.directive("goodbye", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    priority: 1,
    link: function(){
      alert("See ya later!");
    }
  }
})
.directive("welcome", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    priority: 2,
    link: function(){
      alert("Howdy!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem comes when you need the same directives inverted for another usecase